Zoom VIdeo SDK errorCode 300 - This account does not exist or does not belong to you
I have cloned git repo videosdk-ui-toolkit-react-sample  from zoom and changed the settings uising my credentials. My credenctial seem all to be correct. but i get this error
I tried to verify my credentials and double check the configuration

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
